# is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript Functions:

```
function DisplayErrorMessage(fieldElement, messageElement, message) {
  alert(fieldElement.name);
  if(canFocus(fieldElement)){
    //fieldElement.focus();
    if(fieldElement.type =="text") {
      fieldElement.select();
    }
  }
  messageElement.style.backgroundColor='red';
  messageElement.innerText = message;  
}
```

And the function that calls this function:

```
function CheckForm(obj, optMsgDiv) {
  if(obj != "") {
    return true;
  } else {
    if(optMsgDiv != "") {
      var messageObj = document.getElementById(optMsgDiv);
      var clearObj = document.getElementById("refUpdMethod");
      var message = getErrorMsg();
      DisplayErrorMessage(clearObj, messageObj, message);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

On one build it works just fine but on my main build I get 
Error: The value of the property 'DisplayErrorMessage' is null or undefined, not a Function object.

Comment: You should avoir global functions. I'm pretty sure this is what causes you trouble.

Comment: Seems that on the main build the function isn't loaded or is being overwritten (can that happen?) before it gets called. There's too little information to figure out more.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you seeing this error message? In some IDE or in the browser?

Looks like DisplayErrorMessage function isn't being found. If both it and CheckForm are in the same js file that's kinda strange, maybe there's some other code that's making parsing fail.

If they are in different files, make sure these files are properly being served by the WebServer.

To avoid this error, always verify if a resource is available before using it: `if('function' == typeof DisplayErrorMessage){ DisplayErrorMessage(...); }` or `if('function' != typeof DisplayErrorMessage) return;`.

Also, avoid comparing objects to empty strings. Instead of `obj != ""` use `'object' == typeof obj`.

Update: as fsgale said, maybe files are being included in wrong order. To avoid this error, avoid executing code as soon as js file is loaded. In file body just define functions and classes, then use a code that's executed after page is loaded to instantiate objects and execute functions. Doing so makes sure all js files are loaded when your code runs, and also makes page rendering a bit faster. For jQuery you can do so:

```
if('function' == typeof $)
    $(document).ready(init);

function init(){
    if('function' != typeof $) return;

    // init my stuff
}
```

Also, always when possible, include js files in the end of HTML document, just before `</body>`.